# how to install Xcode documentation by dmg file

Tags: documentation

i can't down Documentation in Xcode because of my network,so i down them from https://developer.apple.com/library/downloads/docset-index.dvtdownloadableindex and install.
but it does't work .i move the file com.apple.adc.documentation.OSX.docset appear to ~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation but it still work

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to install them. It works fine in Xcode 7.0:

1. At first you should find your proper item in the below link:
   https://developer.apple.com/library/downloads/docset-index.dvtdownloadableindex

For example the following:

```
<!-- START iOS 9 doc set -->
<dict>
  <key>fileSize</key>
  <integer>1065107366</integer>
  <key>identifier</key>
  <string>com.apple.adc.documentation.iOS</string>
  <key>name</key>
  <string>iOS 9.0 Documentation</string>
  <key>source</key>
  <string>https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/docsets/20150916/031-34987-A.dmg</string>
  <key>userInfo</key>
  <dict>
    <key>ActivationPredicate</key>
    <string>$XCODE_VERSION &gt;= '7.0' &amp;&amp; $XCODE_VERSION &lt; '7.1'</string>
    <key>Category</key>
    <string>Documentation</string>
    <key>IconType</key>
    <string>IDEDownloadablesTypeDocSet</string>
    <key>InstallPrefix</key>
    <string>$(HOME)/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets</string>
    <key>InstalledIfAllReceiptsArePresentOrNewer</key>
    <dict>
      <key>com.apple.pkg.7.0.iOSDocset</key>
      <string>10.9.0.0.1.1442278660</string>
    </dict>
    <key>RequiresADCAuthentication</key>
    <false/>
    <key>Summary</key>
    <string>My description of content</string>
  </dict>
  <key>version</key>
  <string>90.9</string>
</dict>
<!-- END iOS 9 doc set -->
```

2. Download the file from `source` string. In our example: https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/docsets/20150916/031-34987-A.dmg
3. Rename the downloaded file using following structure:

`"identifier string" + "-" + "version string" + ".dmg"`

In our example:
`com.apple.adc.documentation.iOS-90.9.dmg`

4. Then place it to:
   `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode/Downloads/`

I suggest you to remove all files with `.dvtdownloadableindex` extension (if any exists).

5. Go to `InstallPrefix` string folder and remove existence related docsets (if any exists).

In our example the folder is `$(HOME)/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets` which refers to `~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets.` Then remove the `com.apple.adc.documentation.iOS.docset` file from there.

(In some cases, `$(DEVELOPER)` refers to `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`).

6. Open Xcode, go to preferences... . In the Download tab, simply click download arrow for the document. You find that the Xcode just pass the download progress and install the document.

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly!